# PHP can not perform soap call from laravel command

Tags: php, laravel, soap, laravel-artisan

I have made a Laravel command that I try to run with a cronjob every minute.

In the command there is some logic that does a soap call. When I run the command through a route that I created everything works fine.

like this:

```
Route::get('test-command', function() {
    Artisan::call('updateRegisterLogs');
});
```

Now when I try to do the same thing in my command on the server like this:

```
php artisan updateRegisterLogs
```

I get the following error:

> Class 'SoapClient' not found

Now I searched on the internet and in my php.ini I removed the `;` before `extension=php_soap.dll` and before `extension=php_openssl.dll` and I've restarted my apache and unfortunately I get the same error.

I am now sure what is going wrong here since my code works but not when executed with artian.

Comment: Have you done the same for the php.ini for PHP Cli?

Comment: @ka_lin I am sorry but I don't know what that is. Where can I find that php.ini for the cli?

Comment: I'm detailing it on an answer

Answer (score 0):

Usually php has various `php.ini` configuration files, typically located on paths like, `/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini` or `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini` so from the problem you are having my guess is that you have uncommented the extension on one of those config files but not the cli path one.

If you have for example the application being served using nginx and phpfpm the `php.ini` file that will determine what modules are enabled when executing php for those requests will be the one located at `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini`. When you execute artisan commands the "selected" config file is the one at `/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.init`

Comment: I don't find any cli folder

Comment: Could you please provide the path where your php.ini file is located?

Comment: /etc/php71 is the path of the php.ini file

Comment: From the command line if you type `php --ini | grep Configuration` it should show you where your ini file resides for the CLI php parser.

Comment: it gives me this result /etc/php.ini but in this php.ini file I can't find anyhting about soap extension of something else about soap, should I add it manualy?

Comment: Yes, you should add in there.

Comment: Look for soap on the folder resulting of executing this: `php -i | grep extension_dir` what output do you get?

Comment: extension_dir => /usr/lib64/php/modules => /usr/lib64/php/modules
sqlite3.extension_dir => no value => no value

Comment: There may be extra INI files too, to see those just take off the `| grep Configuration` part of `php --ini`.  Worst case you might need to install the php soap module from your package manager of choice or gui web management interface.