# Laravel Artisan command for soap call "Class 'SoapClient' not found"

Tags: php, laravel, soap

I have an artisan command where I do a soap call.

So I use the SoapClient

```
use SoapClient;
```

When I test run my command from an url like this:

```
Route::get('test-command', function() {
    Artisan::call('updateRegisterLogs');
});
```

Everything works great!

Now when I try to run it with artisan on my linux server to test the command to create a cronjob I get the following error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
>
> Class 'SoapClient' not found

The weird thing is I even get this error when I try a simple `php artisan` to see a list of all my commands.

Why does my artisan break from this? My code works fine but artisan doesn't.

Comment: post the code of "updateRegisterLogs" command

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz it's a lot of code, the code works fine. I've tested it with calling the command via an url as shown in my question. The problem is my artisan breaks because of the `Class SoapClient not found` error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP can not perform soap call from laravel command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55572708/php-can-not-perform-soap-call-from-laravel-command)

Comment: @namelivia that question is not yet answered correctly since it has nothing to do with php.ini files. I reverted the changes in php.ini files and and my code still works fine but still same error

Comment: did you try? `use \SoapClient`, add a \ before SoapClient, because it's working for me

Comment: yes I've tried that, same error unfortunately

Comment: did you check that, is Soap client installed on your server?

you can check that using `phpinfo();`

Comment: @Sethu I can execute soap calls from my code when I run the command with a route as explained in my question so yes soap client is installed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391442/fatal-error-class-soapclient-not-found

Comment: @DevinGray As you can read in my question I am using a linux server not windows machine so I don't need no dll's

Comment: The php CLI Version on your Server differs from the php version of your webserver (apache, nginx).
On the command line you use e.g. php5.6 where ext-soap is NOT installed, and apache uses php7.2 where ext-soap IS installed

check both php Versions:
php -v
phpinfo();

artisan takes the cli version

Comment: @IFR is there perhaps a way to not use the cli version? make a command that redirects to a route or something

Comment: I would create a new class which handles your command code, then calls this class function from your command, or in your route function.

Or make an alias inside your bash profile to use the correct php version
or don't use Artisan::call rather use exec('php7.2 artisan <command>');

Answer (score 1):

The PHP version and also the CLI ini file could be different from the web one and when running command with artisan you are using the php cli.
Check with 
`php -r "echo phpinfo();"`
If your php cli has soap enabled.